# What is wrong with the height of my Android ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve a layout with a button and `EditText` and a `Buttton` at the top of the screen, a `TextView` at the bottom, and a `ListView` that vertically fills the space behind them. Last night I had this more or less correct, except for using an absolute height for the `ListView`, just to test the app's processing.

I don't know what has happened since I closed Android Studio then and opened it now, maybe magic, maybe a stuff up with the Git repo, or maybe an unconscious change by me, but now the `ListView` seems to extend infinitely downward off the display, as highlighted by the orange outline in this pic:

[image]

I have tried various `layout_height` values, and it is `50dp` for the above pic. Even as low as `10dp` makes no difference, and trying to drag it smaller by using the mouse on the top blue anchor line makes no difference.

What is wrong here and where should I be looking to try and resolve this?

Here is the XML for the layout, in all its broken glory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context="com.bradykelly.heavyweights.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:text="@string/adjustment_label"
        android:id="@+id/scale_text_view_label"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:height="10dp"/>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/process_file_text" />
<ListView
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="@drawable/text_view_border"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you want the `ListView` below the `TextView` but you don't want the infinite downward?

Comment: Post your *xml* code for above image.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the layout XML ?

Comment: use layout_weight and LinearLayout as parent View.....

Comment: there is something wrong with your XML. And while you don't show it, you will have to deal with it by yourself

Comment: I have added the XML.

Comment: @ProfK Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have made some changes to your layout using `layout_weight` property. Apply below `xml` code into your `Layout`. Using below `layout` will show you the fit into screen `List view` as i have attached in `screen shot`.
>
> Because you have given `List view height=50` and also you have given `weight` so it cause problem.
>
> `You not need to define height when you are using weight property in your layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scale_text_view_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Adjustment Label"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Process" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Testeing"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this most quick and correct answer.

Comment: @ProfK Glad to help you sir :).

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
android:layout_weight="50"
```

for listview but weight sum is 1 in the linear layout. That is the problem for listview.

Use like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

<Textview
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

weight count should be matched with weight sum. Parent Layout should be fillparent and Make your height 0dp for all child layouts.

Comment: I have already accepted an answer, but thank you for the info on weight and weight sum.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `layout_weight` only in `ListView`. Check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/scale_text_view_label"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/processButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="test" />
    <ListView
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot see the listview in this layout.